# Android - Downloading a file from server getting terminated

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

We are trying to download an apk file which is nearly 7MB from server. While reading the data from input stream the flow is getting terminated. We are not getting any error message. Below is the code we tired.

```
   URL url = new URL(versionUpgradeModel.getUrl());
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
connection.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000);
connection.connect();

long totalBytes = 0;

// expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
// instead of the file
if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    totalBytes = connection.getContentLength();
}

String filePath = localFilePath + "/TestApp.apk";
CWTSLog.e("FILE", "CREATED" + localFilePath);
OutputStream outputStream = null;
try

{
    // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    int bufferszie = 4096;
    int read = 0;
    double consumedBytes = 0;
    double progress = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferszie];
    CWTSLog.e("TAG", "LENGTH " + totalBytes);
    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        CWTSLog.e("Read: ", "" + read);
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        consumedBytes += read;
        CWTSLog.e("CONSUMED BYTE", "" + consumedBytes);
        progress = (consumedBytes / totalBytes) * 100;
        CWTSLog.e("PROGRESS", "" + progress);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
    }

}
```

We tried to debug, but the it stopped at reading input stream after 7%. But while using the same url in browser its downloading fine. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: what is connection timeout for this operation?

Comment: +1 for checking the timeout and any other request/response headers. Compare those sent/received in the browser with those in the app. At last, put them in your question so we can see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced similar problem, my video used to get downloaded only upto 5Mb and then get failed.
My problem was when I was in initialising bufferedInputStream(). 
Don't give size, I have commented that part. Try it.

Use this code:

```
/**
 * downloadVideoAsyntask aysnctask is used to download video from server.
 */

class DownlaodVideoAsyntask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Utils.showProgressDialog(mActivity, "Downloading...", false);
        isAsyntaskWorking = true;
    };

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        Utils.showLog(TAG, values[0]);
    };

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 5000;// 5sec
        final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 30000;// 30sec
        String imageURL = params[0];
        Utils.showLog(TAG, imageURL);
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i(TAG, "image download beginning: " + imageURL);

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/" + AppHelper.STORED_VIDEO_PATH);
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }

        String fname = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".avi";
        file = new File(myDir, fname);

        // Open a connection to that URL.
        URLConnection ucon = null;
        try {
            ucon = url.openConnection();
            lengthofFile = ucon.getContentLength();
            Utils.showLog("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lengthofFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // this timeout affects how long it takes for the app to realize
        // there's
        // a connection problem
        ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

        // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = ucon.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        // new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 18);
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

        long total = 0;

        // Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to
        // read(-1)
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                total += len;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthofFile));
                outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            }

            // clean up
            outStream.flush();
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "download completed in "
                + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                + " sec");
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        Utils.hideProgressDialog();
        isAsyntaskWorking = false;
        if (result) {
            // if successfully download the video.
            Utils.showToast(mActivity,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toast_video_success));
        } else {
            Utils.showToast(mActivity,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toast_video_fail));

            // deleting partially downloaded file.
            file.delete();
        }
    };

}
```